# Difference between sending a function name as a parameter vs explicitly identifying it as a function

Tags: javascript

Sorry if the title isn't clear but I don't know the correct terminology, so basically what is the difference between this:

```
doSomething(servletPath,
    function () {
        checkErrors();
    }, function () {
        init();
    }, function () {
        showErrorMsj();
    }
);
```

And this:

`doSomething(servletPath, checkErrors, init, showErrorMsj);`

Both seem to work the same on an old legacy project I am maintaining but I would like to know if one is preferred to the other and why.

Comment: [This](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/function-callback-risks/) also might be worth taking a look at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is in the parameters and `this` context. If the functions don't accept any parameters, or if the `doSomething` doesn't pass any parameters, the code is equivalent.

If, say, `checkErrors` *did* accept a parameter, and `doSomething` calls the functions with parameters, then doing

```
function () {
    checkErrors();
},
```

instead of

```
checkErrors,
```

would result in `checkErrors` being called with no arguments, instead of with whatever argument(s) the `doSomething` passed.

On a similar note, the

```
function () {
    checkErrors();
},
```

will call `checkErrors` with no calling context (the `this` inside it will be either the global object or `undefined`). But if you do

```
checkErrors,
```

then the `doSomething` will have the ability to call it with a different calling context. (It won't *necessarily* do so, but it would be doable)

Comment: "the code is equivalent" -- logically, yes but an extra function object might get allocated.